# Pushing elements into array as copy

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In prototypejs, why does the following code remove the matching divs from the #test div?

What confuses me is that this happens when they are being inserted in the #droparea, and not when they are being pushed in the array.

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="foo" id="22.1234">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="foo" id="22.1235">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="foo" id="53.2345">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="foo" id="53.2346">
        4
    </div>
</div>

<div id="droparea">

</div>
```

js

```
var elArray = [];
var els = $('test').select('.foo');

els.each(function(x){ if(x.id.split('.')[0] == 22){ elArray.push(x); } });
elArray.each(function(y){ $('droparea').insert({ bottom: y }); });
```

Comment: Please use valid IDs in your code. They must start with a letter, not a number. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-id

Comment: It's just for example. My "real" code is much more complicated, I made this example just to show you the principle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you want to copy/clone the elements into the drop area, not move them?

This thread on Google Groups discusses [how to clone an element](http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/5d1c7b0eea3e8121). Note in particular the caveats about changing the ID before reinserting to the document.

Comment: Works for me, but I still don't get it why it behaves like this :)

Comment: Because there's only one element, and you've just pushed it into the other area. When you store an element in an array, you're only storing a reference to it, not a copy of it.